# hover/mouseover not activated on every move inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chartjs v.1.0.2 and trying to set a point dot only to appear on hover over current point. Same problem is when i use hover or mouseover. Current point can be found with `getPointsAtEvent(e);` but it only works if i move mouse out of canvas, and then return it back in, not while i move inside the canvas. How can it work work every time i move mouse inside canvas element?

```
window.onload = function(){

        var ctx = $("#chart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
                var chart1 = new Chart(ctx).Line(data1, options);


                $("#chart1").hover(function(e) {
                    var activeBars = chart1.getPointsAtEvent(e); 
                    activeBars[0].display = true;
//                    console.log(activeBars[0]);
                    chart1.update();
                 });

    };

    var data1 = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(95,186,88,0.7)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                }
            ]
    };



var options = {
    responsive: true,
    bezierCurve : false,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    scaleFontSize: 0,
    pointDot : false,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(232,232,232)",
    showTooltips: true,

    customTooltips: function (tooltip) {
        var tooltipEl = $('#chartjs-tooltip');

        if (!tooltip) {
            tooltipEl.css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            return;
        }

        tooltipEl.removeClass('above below');
        tooltipEl.addClass(tooltip.yAlign);

        // split out the label and value and make your own tooltip here
        var parts = tooltip.text.split(":");
        var innerHtml = '<span>' + parts[0].trim() + '</span> : <span><b>' + parts[1].trim() + '</b></span>';
        tooltipEl.html(innerHtml);

        tooltipEl.css({
            opacity: 1,
            left: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetLeft + tooltip.x + 'px',
            top: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetTop + tooltip.y + 'px',
            fontFamily: tooltip.fontFamily,
            fontSize: tooltip.fontSize,
            fontStyle: tooltip.fontStyle,
        });
    }

};
```

simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aehhusx/2/)

Comment: which browser you are testing on?, as i can see it is running ok on firefox

Comment: Firefox, but it doesn't work properly in any. It shows point dot only when i leave canvas and reenter it again, and it should show different dots as i move through canvas element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `pointDot` option to true.

```
...
pointDot : true,
...
```

Then set the `pointColor` and `pointStrokeColor` for the series to transparent and the `pointHighlightFill` and `pointHighlightStroke` to a non transparent value, like so

```
...
    pointColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    pointStrokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    pointHighlightFill: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p1zgp5ys/

Answer (score 0):

ok, i got your issue, just set the  pointDot value to true as mentioned below:

```
pointDot : true,
```

in **var** options

that's it :)

Comment: it is false on purpose :) i want them hidden, so that they are not visible by default, instead only a clean line, and then on hover just show one dot. If it is true, all dots are visible...